# Insect inside the display of the iPad Retina

Tags: ipad, screen, bug, display

Yesterday I found a bug inside my iPad display. I mean, *literally* a bug. My wife was reading some magazine and noticed something moving inside the screen. I thought it was some kind of animation, took a closer look, and noticed that it was a very small bug crawling very slowly.

We shook the iPad to see if it would stop, fall to an edge, or something like that. But instead, it got stuck in the top right section of the screen, and now seems to be dead.

The iPad was bought 3 months ago. I think it's under warranty and currently trying to contact Apple about it.

My questions are:

1 - Have someone seen a bug inside an iPad before?

2 - I know that the iPad isn't waterproof, but is it that easy for a bug to get inside it?

Comment: First [Grace Hopper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper), now you. You're in good company at least!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug could conceivably get in through the 30-pin port, Lightning port, or the headphone jack. Since your iPad is so new an Apple retail store would probably give you a new one without any hassle. Make sure to back it to your computer or iCloud before taking it to the store.

Comment: I would agree with this totally. I see no reason why a bug would care it were crawling into a headphone port as opposed to any other nook or cranny it might want to explore for food or shelter or just on it's random walk through the world.